# Is there a line that separates two sets of points?

Tags: algorithms

> You have two $n$-point sets $P$ and $Q$ of two-dimensional points:
>   $$
> P = \{p_1,\dots,p_n\}, \text{ where } p_i = \{a_i, b_i\} \\
> Q = \{q_1,\dots,q_n\}, \text{ where } q_i = \{c_i, d_i\}
> $$
>
> You must determine whether there is a line $L$ so that $P$ and $Q$ are on opposite sides. This line essentially must separate both of the sets. The algorithm must run in $O(n)$, and is aimed to be deterministic (yes or no).

Could anyone provide help regarding this problem?

Comment: Do you have any thoughts about the problem at all? Can you come up with *any* algorithm?

Comment: It's a nice problem, where did it come from? It's related to SVMs.